# Jquery - Change textbox to text on click

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on an online booking system, basically I want a textbox to change to paragraph text when a user clicks on a button.
Basically, removing the textbox and just displaying the value that is inserted.

This is the HTML of the textbox that I want changing:

```
<input type="text" class="input-txt-xxxsml left" id="txt-pickup-hn" name="txt-pickup-hn" tabindex="1" value="" />
```

And this is the HTML for the button that I want so when the user clicks it, it changes the textbox to just text:

```
<button class="btn-med ui-button ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-all btn-hover-anim btn-row-wrapper left" name="btn-row-wrapper" >Search</button>
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean just text? your original input type is already equal to text

Comment: do you want to change the text of textbox or add another content.. please clarify the question

Comment: Basically, when a user clicks the button, it removes the textbox and just displays the <p>value</p> if that makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/muSYu/1/

```
$('#textify').click(function() {
    $('input').replaceWith(function() {
        return '<div>' + $(this).val() + '</div>';
    });
})​
```

For your example:

```
$('.btn-med').click(function() { 
   $('#txt-pickup-hn').replaceWith(function() { 
      return '<div>' + $(this).val() + '</div>';
   });
});
```

You should really give your button an ID by the way :)

Answer (score 1):

Are trying to achieve this effect? http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/L7dWc/

html

```
<input type="text" value="lorem ipsum">
<button type="button">search</button>
```

javascript

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
var i = $('input'),
    v = i.val();

    if ($(this).hasClass('search')) {
       $('p').remove();    
    }
    else {
       $('<p></p>', { text: v }).insertBefore(i);
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('search');
});
```

css

```
p + input { display: none; }
```

if you click twice on search button you can show again and update the input

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function fillTextBox(){
var box = $("#box");
box.val("Hello World");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="box" type="text" class="input-txt-xxxsml left" id="txt-pickup-hn" name="txt-pickup-hn" tabindex="1" value="" />
<button  name="btn-row-wrapper" OnClick="fillTextBox()" >Search</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the button add an onClick that calls a javascript function:

```
<button onclick='javascript:changeText()' />
```

Then in the function do:

```
$('#txt-pickup-hn').text('new text');
```